# What is this violin ornament?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, rests

Pictured below is an excerpt from Sibelius’s *Tapiola*, (Bar 460):

[image: A few bars of an orchestral score showing the parts for violins I and II. A squiggle-like symbol appears above some notes. One of these symbols is circled.]

It looks to me like a trill/mordent on its side, to fit into the condensed score. But is it?

Comment: Extreme gladness that people have taken the time to be helpful without making any attempt to make me feel stupid. More power to their elbows!

Answer (score 39):

It's not an ornament; it's a quarter rest. The Violins I are divided, and the upper half play rest + quarter note while the lower half play half notes.

Answer (score 10):

It's rests for separate voices.  If you got a "div." for the passage at some place before, the violin I section is divided into two groups playing two voices.

If not, you start playing an E5 on the A string on beat 1, then tilt the bow on beat 2 to play the same note on the E string as well.  Rinse, repeat.  Two voices on a single instrument.  The second bar, however, makes this interpretation rather unlikely since it would require distributing the voices across D and A string in a manner and positions that are unlikely to sound good in an orchestral setting.

Comment: Yes, there was a previous Divisi I didn’t include.